# What does the plugins-section in a Gradle-build file precisely?

Tags: android, gradle, continuous-integration

What does the call

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
```

exactly?

Does it download the plugins from the in 'settings' defined repositories? Or are the plugins already available locally and it just loads them for the build?